# Why does downcast unboxing result in exception?

Tags: c#

I cannot figure out, why the following code results in exception?

```
static class Utility<T>
{
    public static TReturn Change<TReturn>(T arg)
    {
        object temp = arg;
        return (TReturn)temp;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 100;

        try
        {
            short s = Utility<int>.Change<short>(i);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

I think my code can be simplified as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        int x = 100;
        object o = x;
        short s = (short)o;
    }
}
```

Comment: @mitch,because I am learning generic. The example above is just a trivial example.

Comment: I don't think (or didn't know) a static class can be generic...

Comment: @MPelletier - Static classes certainly can be generic.

Comment: @Greg: Thanks! Though in this case it's not doing anything...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're unboxing `temp` which is really an `int` directly into a `short`, that's why the cast fails.  Instead, you have to unbox to the right type (`int`) first, and then do the integer cast:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 100;
        object temp = i;
        try
        {
            short s0 = (short)i;
            short s1 = (short)(int)temp;
            short s2 = (short)temp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }
    }
}
```

See Eric Lippert's [Representation and Identity](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/) blog entry for lots of details.

Comment: OK. But if you revisit my code above, returning (TResult)(T)temp; will not compile.

Comment: Michael B gave me a solution  using dynamic. By returning (TResult)(arg as dynamic); we no longer need boxing to object and code still compiles.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said it is illegal to unbox a value type to the wrong type. A quick solution is to change the parameters type to dynamic or to do this:

```
return (T)(value as dynamic);
```

You'll pay some costs but the dlr does resolve value types to the right type for unboxing.

Comment: Good solution. I can compile the code without having to do boxing to object.

Comment: The as keyword should have been a hint that this is boxing. As cant be used on value types.This actually is a call to box to object then invoke the dynamic runtime to figure out how to safely unbox.

Comment: @Dan and @Michael, a guy from my other thread let me know another way, i.e., return (TReturn)Convert.ChangeType(arg, typeof(TReturn));

Comment: This is a boxing call on invoke and return and requires your value types to support iconvertible. It wont work on nullables

Answer (score 1):

A direct 'cast' of an integer value is actually a conversion.  When the value is boxed, the compiler cannot emit an appropriate conversion, so it attempts to cast the value instead.  Since the types are not the same (Int16 and Int32 are different types), the unboxing and cast fails.

<strike>On a side note, I'm guessing the code works if you omit the temporary variable that forces the boxing to Object.</strike>

Comment: For my code above, I use generic paramater to do casting. Boxing to object is mandatory to make it compilable.

Answer (score 1):

Eric Lippert has a detailed blog entry on the topic of [Representation and Identity](http://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/). Which explains why you must unbox to either the original type or a Nullable<> of the original type.

Answer (score -2):

You are tying to cast an integer (int) to a short integer (short). Since an int is larger than a short int with regards to the number of bits it supports, there is a possibility that the original int has a value that is too large for the short int. To notify you of this issue, the runtime notes that the cast -- as with any cast where a value is cast to something smaller -- is not allowed.

In a 32-bit system, for example, an int stores values in 32 bits and a short stores values in 16 bits. What would happen with a 32-bit int with a value of 4,000,000 that would be cast to a 16-bit short? There are not enough bits in the short variable to store a value of 4,000,000. What would you expect to see in that case? The runtime is alerting you to this overflow condition.

Comment: explicit casting should allow to cast int to short.