# Casting object type in c#

Tags: c#, casting

I ran into an issue today and I wasn't entirely sure why it wouldn't work.

The following code sample will crash:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     int i32 = 10;
     object obj = i32;
     long i64 = (long)obj;
}
```

This will result in an InvalidCastException.  Why does this not work?  Is C# not smart enough to know that the object is actually of type int?

I've already come up with a workaround, but I'm curious as to why the above code sample didn't work in the first place.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: I note that this is a duplicate of many previous questions, including most recently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911293

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no cast available from a boxed Int32 to an Int64.
Making an intermediate cast to `int` should work, because the compiler is willing to generate this:

```
// verify obj is a boxed int, unbox it, and perform the *statically*
// known steps necessary to convert an int to a long
long i64 = (long) ((int)obj);
```

but not (hypothetically) this:

```
// Find out what type obj *actually* is at run-time and perform 
// the-known-only-at-run-time steps necessary to produce  
// a long from it, involving *type-specific* IL instructions  
long i64 = (long)obj;
```

Here's a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx) by Eric Lippert about this.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx) by Eric Lippert for the gory details.

The gist of it is that it would be very slow for the compiler to figure out (by trial and error, since `object` can be anything at all) what type has been boxed and whether or not it can be safely cast.

Answer (score 1):

You mean the compiler or the runtime?

The runtime is smart enough, so it throws the `InvalidCastException`. The compiler however cannot know for sure what type your object is, since you boxed your int.

> Boxing and unboxing enable value types
>   to be treated as objects. Boxing a
>   value type packages it inside an
>   instance of the Object  reference
>   type.

So since its boxed as an object, the compiler won't complain about it.

See more information on boxing and unboxing here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk%28VS.80%29.aspx